# C# Helix Toolkit how to draw a rectangular prism between points?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying to draw a shape between two points (represented as `Point3D` objects).

The goal is to create a path/road from point A to B as a rectangular prism, so it would be flat and short on the sides (e.g. a length of 10, a width of 3, and a height of 1, with the ends of the shape at each point).

So far, I've tried creating a box shape using Helix Toolkit's built-in helper methods, using the midpoint between the points as the center:

```
AddBox(Point3D center, Vector3D x, Vector3D y, double xlength, double ylength, double zlength, BoxFaces faces = BoxFaces.All)
```

The problem is I don't understand if or how I can control the rotation and angle of the box so that it will connect the two points if they are diagonal from each other or at different heights.

Is there a way to achieve this more elegantly? Maybe something more like the AddTube method which supplies points as a path?:

```
AddTube(IList<Point3D> path, double diameter, int thetaDiv, bool isTubeClosed)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find the following solution [here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/draw-interlocked-tetrahedrons-in-a-cage-of-line-segments-using-wpf-and-c/).

Essentially, I just refitted the code at that link to do what I needed to do. I adjusted the scale factor for thickness and width, as well as made an enum that I can switch on to set the prism's direction:

```
Vector3D dir = new Vector3D();
switch (faceDirection)
{
    case VectorUpFace.Up:
        dir = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
        break;
    case VectorUpFace.Left:
        dir = new Vector3D(0, -1, 0);
        break;
     case VectorUpFace.Right:
        dir = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
        break;
     case VectorUpFace.Front:
        dir = new Vector3D(1, 0, 0);
        break;
 }
```

Then, the `dir` vector is used in the call to `ScaleVector` (see the link at the beginning of this answer).